# Trying to make a button in Unreal Engine affect all levels

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I'm working on a Pong-like game and I'm having difficulty with getting the button in the PaddleColors widget to affect all levels. (Menu, 1vAI, 1v1Game, 2v2Game)

For a button example: I set up the blueprint so that when I click the Green button in the Menu, it changes the left paddle to green.[image: Menu widget -> Settings widget -> PaddleColors widget]

When I click it in the level "Menu" in the Menu widget -> Settings widget -> PaddleColors widget, it changes the left paddle to green. This is good. However, when I then open up "1v1Game" level, the left paddle goes back to blue (Default color).

I'm trying to make it so that when I change the left paddle to green, it will stay green on all levels. Here is my blueprint for when I change the paddle to green: [image]

The actor class is the left paddle blueprint. The set material is the green paddle material.

Answer (score 0):

you clearly want to use a save game object to do this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf98GRZA2d8 (System used to save progress or whatever you want to keep)

You will have to save the specified material (green, blue, red) when you click on the colored buttons, then you will load that material every time you start the level.
Let me know if you need any further.